# JQuery - Position overlay div over another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to lay one div over another. IE reports "Invalid Argument". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

```
 var left = $("#container").offset().left;
 var top = $("#container").offset().top;
 $("#overlay").css({"left":left + "px", "top":top + "px"});
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but have you set your positions to be absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently.. you cannot return false when calling the above method.

```
onclick="toggleOverlay();return true"
```

The above worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must include return value from the function you call in an onclick. If you do not, it will become undefined and not run at all.

Without  seeing the full function definition it is hard to say what was the full issue with your code.